# ASP.NET Razor Pages won't load Partial View when I return Page()

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to load a partial view, with GET, and it's kind of working. I get
localhost(somenumbers)/AnkietaGlowna?View=nowy
and then this code is working:

```
@if (Model.View == "nowy") { Html.RenderPartial("Nowy"); }
@if (Model.View == "wycieczki") { Html.RenderPartial("Wycieczki"); }
```

But when the ModelState is invalid, then it

```
return Page();
```

And the url stays the same
localhost(somenumbers)/AnkietaGlowna?View=nowy, but it doesn't render the partial view. In my my AnkietaGlowna.cshtml.cs I have this OnGet Function:

```
public ActionResult OnGet(string View)
    {
        this.View = View;
        if(this.View != "nowy" && this.View != "wycieczki")
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");

        return Page();
    }
```

After the return Page() in:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     return Page();
```

It doean't work, how can I make this work? 
Thanks for the help

EDIT: It's working, before my

```
public string View { get; set; }
```

I just add

```
[BindProperty]
```

Comment: "It doean't work" - what happens?

Comment: It won't load the partial view. I suspect that when I reload rhe page it loses the variable View but when i wrote [BindProperty] it pases the value of View and it's working

Comment: it might be because you don't pass the model when you return page hence view property would be empty, try `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page(Model);`